# LLVM IR: initialize and cast [20 x i8]

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to initialize and then cast a number of LLVM IR variables in the following way:

```
store i64 %content, i64* %5
%tt2 = load i64, i64* %5
%ttt2 = trunc i64 %tt2 to i32
```

While this seems trivial and works fine, I am trapped to do the same thing for a `[20 * i8]` typed variable. Something like:

```
store [20 x i8] %content, [20 x i8]* %5
%tt2 = load [20 x i8], [20 x i8]* %5
%ttt2 = trunc [20 x i8] %tt2 to i32
```

Currently I got the following error msg for the third line:

> invalid cast opcode for cast from `[20 x i8]` to `i32`

Could anyone shed some lights on this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `trunc` from one int to another, but not from an array to an int. That's just how `trunc` is defined — if the input isn't an int, then trunc would need to do something markedly different from "drop the higher-order bits and preserve the lower-order bits".

I think the most common approach is to cast the pointer and then load/store from a pointer that already matches the type you want to load/store.

(Note that `%ttt2` etc. aren't LLVM variables, they're LLVM values. They don't vary, ever.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment arnt. Could you elaborate a bit more on how to `cast the pointer and then load/store from that pointer`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You tried to `load` and then `trunc` the loaded value. Instead of doing that, you can `bitcast` the pointer (`%5`) to `i32*` and then `load` the cast pointer, which gives you an `i32`. If you use the C++ API, `CastInst::Create(CastInst::BitCast, ...`

Comment: I see.. Thanks! I am directly working on LLVM IR (with my own Python script to process the string representation of it). Let me see how it works!